# Injecting object to Rest controller in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new to spring.
I want to inject object of type 'A' to my Restcontroller.
I don't have application-context where I can create beans for 'A'.
I would like to know how do it.
I am using spring MVC to expose a REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show the way:

1- Your class should be annotated with @Component, @Service or @Repository:

```
@Component
public class A {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello from class A";
    }
}
```

2- In your controller you should declare a data member of your class

3- Create a constructor and annotate it with @Autowired, or you may annotate the data member itself with @Autowired, but it's not a good practice:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/my-rest-controller")
public class MyRestController {
    
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    public MyRestController(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMessage(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(a.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You may call the api using postman or your browser by the following URL:
http://localhost:8080/api/my-rest-controller/message

Comment: Great,. since it works fine, I'd appreciated If you could consider the answer is true.